# Change multiline EditText cursor position without opening keyboard

Tags: java, android

I am creating a dialog that has a EditText in it. The dialog takes more than half the screen and the logic of the dialog doesn't allow to use a keyboard.

I was using this solution [Android 4.0 EditText without soft keyboard and with cursor positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13811080/android-4-0-edittext-without-soft-keyboard-and-with-cursor-positioning) but I found out that when you have a multi line EditText, it doesn't work since you can only select the first line.

Is there a solution available for multi-line EditText?

For single-line, this works:

```
if(v.getId() == R.id.emo_text_field){
    Layout layout = ((EditText) v).getLayout();
    float x = event.getX() + v.getScrollX();
    int offset = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(0, x);
    if(offset>0){
        if(x>layout.getLineMax(0)){
            ((EditText) v).setSelection(offset);     // touch was at end of text
        }
        else{
            ((EditText) v).setSelection(offset - 1);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem?iam also facing same issue when using multiline edittext

Comment: @user1213202 Yes sorry, I wrote my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested, this is the solution I found for this:

```
public void disableSoftInputFromAppearing(EditText editText) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        editText.setTextIsSelectable(true);
    } else {
        editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        editText.setFocusable(true);
    }
}
```

And in your onCreate, just put:

```
disableSoftInputFromAppearing(editTextView);
```

That way, the keyboard won't appear on any SDK version of Android. Hope it helps someone else.